# How to import from saved QPython file?

Tags: qpython

With QPython on Kindle fire .. I use QEdit to write & save a .py file .. say bob.py ..

But when I switch to Console, I can't IMPORT from bob ..

Can someone tell me how to do this?

John (new to QPython)

Comment: Where do you save your file?

Comment: the location shows as "Scripts" in QEdit ... also as "/sdcard/com.hipal.qpyplus/scripts"

Comment: My apologies for slow my slow response ... was away from computer

Comment: I misread ... that should have been ... "/sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/scripts"

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Yulia V got me thinking, maybe I just needed to append the location of "Scripts" to the sys.path,  and Yep, that worked fine!!

Thanks Yulia!

Comment: Could you please say how to set the sys.path? (new to python)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can save the module file into the same directory which you script locates or  /sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/lib/python2.7/site-packages/